# Get path with quotes from JFileChooser?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Is it possible to let user enters a path with quotes in JFileChooser and get this path without quotes?

For example the user puts: `"c:\path\to\File"`  in the File name text field. but when I got the selected file I got the current directory + `"c:\path\to\File"`. Is their a way to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Use String.replaceAll method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like so:

```
String str = "\"C:\\foor\\bar\"";
System.out.println(str);
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\"?(.+?)\"?", "$1");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

prints:

> "C:\foo\bar"
>
> C:\foo\bar

This will remove the quotes (`"`) which are exactly at the beginning and end of the string. The `?` in the regular expression denotes that the quotes might not be there, so for instance, the following should all yield the same result:

> "C:\foo\bar"
>
> "C:\foo\bar
>
> C:\foo\bar"
>
> C:\foo\bar

However, to my knowledge, the `"` character does not make part of a valid file path, so you might get around just by doing: `str.replaceAll("\"","");`.

EDIT: Seeing your comment and question edit, I made this short piece of code which seems to do what you are after. That said, I will not be removing my previous answer just in case someone else might find it useful.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setDialogTitle("Hello");
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(f) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
{ 
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (file.getName().contains("\""))
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"?(.*?)\"?");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(file.getName());
        if (m.matches())
        {
            System.out.println("Group Found: " + m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to do what you are after, I have pasted the following in the File text box: `"C:\foo\bar.txt"` and the code printed `C:\foo\bar.txt`, excluding the initial segment.

Comment: What about the current directory that gets added to the path. JFileChooser suppose that the path with quotes is the file name and adds the current directory as parent

Comment: @FerasOdeh: I have changed my answer, this should do what you need.

Comment: Don't see how it would work as `\"?(.*?)\"?` will match an empty string.

Comment: @dacwe: You do have a point, however if the user does not provide text, the `JFileChooser`'s open button will do nothing. If the user just passes in `""`, then, the OP could make other checks.

Comment: No, no, that is not what I mean, that regular expression will match the empty spaces between all characters in any string.